# Javascript functions in custom namespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to declare 2 more functions in main function like this ?

```
var jquery4u = {
    init: function() {
        jquery4u.countdown.show();
    },
    countdown: function() {
        show: function() {
            console.log('show');
        },
        hide: function() {
            console.log('hide');
        }
    }
}
jquery4u.init();
```

and i receive the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( on this line "show: function() {"

Comment: What happens when you try it? Did it work? If not, why not? (It won't work because of invalid syntax.. a function is not an object literal and so those 'keys' - show, hide - are really labels.)

Comment: `show` and `hide` need to be inside of an object `{}` not a `function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `function` from the right of the `countdown` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/cs0mh94w/))

```
var jquery4u = {
    init: function() {
        jquery4u.countdown.show();
    },
    countdown: {
        show: function() {
            console.log('show');
        },
        hide: function() {
            console.log('hide');
        }
    }
}
jquery4u.init();
```

Next time, use jsFiddle to make a demo and click the "JSHint" button.

Comment: ohhh thank you @Mottie !! also it's a new feature for me that "jshint".. haha thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, none of this will work. Unless you make countdown an object or you treat its sub-functions as proper functions.
Why: Under countdown, you created an instance of object not a function.

```
var jquery4u = {
    countdown: function() {
        show = function() {
            console.log('show');
        }
        hide = function() {
            console.log('hide');
        }

        jquery4u.countdown.show();
    }
}
```

The above code is a valid code so it is possible. Unfortunately it will not return anything.

The proper way to do this is in this format:

```
var jquery4u = {
    countdown: {
        show: function() {
            console.log('show');
        },
        hide: function() {
            console.log('hide');
        }
    }
}
```

This will work. You can try it out by calling:

```
jquery4u.countdown.show();
```